# Can an employer REQUIRE a foreign W-8 sub-contractor to have a US/stateside bank account for the employer to submit payment for services?

Tags: united-states, employment, international

As an employer receiving services from a foreign individual ([W-8BEN](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/w/w8form.asp) completed), can the employer require the W-8 employee to have a US bank account to send their contracted payroll?
I don't think that we (the employer) can, but I wanted to see if I could get either confirmation or clarification on this please.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The employer isn't required to impose that condition, but can require an employee to create a particular bank account for the employer's administrative convenience.

In general, under U.S. law, the answer to questions in the form "Can the employer require . . . ?" is "yes" unless a specific statute or common law legal requirement says otherwise and no such limitation applies in this case.